# Tidal Scheduler: Dynamic Job/Create job programmatically

Tags: c#, tidal-scheduler

Okay, I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible, but I'm hoping it is.

We currently use CISCO's Tidal Scheduler for a variety of tasks, one of which is related to the import of files from partners- specifically detecting the files, decrypting them (when necessary), and moving them to a processing directory.

**The Problem**

Because of business decisions over which I have no control, partners FTP one of two files to us into one of 15 directories; we then write responses to one of 15 OTHER directories.  In Tidal, this means we create 60 jobs for each new vendor.

The folder structure and up-to 60 files thing is not going to change.  However inconvenient it is.

So, I'm looking for one of two solutions:

1. (preferred): Create a dynamic job which can watch the
   subdirectories of a given root folder and then run a single job
   based on the folder in which a file was found and the specific
   filename.
2. A programmatic way to create and insert new jobs in
       Tidal, so that we at least don't have to set up these 60 jobs per
       partner by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Tidal has a REST API that you can use to programmaticaly do any task available in client user interface, and sometimes more than that. There is no library that you can use to use the api that I know, but is not difficult to use a standard REST client to make the requests. Just follow the instructions from:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/datacenter_mgmt/Tidal_Enterprise_Scheduler/6-2/rest_api_reference/guide/Cisco_TES_6-2_REST_API_Reference_Guide.html

You can even play with the different requests and responses using the apidoc on your server:  `http://<yourtidalserver>:<port>/apidoc/TES6-DEV/`

Comment: Just about "standard REST client", YOu can't use Postman AFAICT because Tidal requires the body, which is in XML, to be urlencoded which Postman won't do. Separately in addition to the helpful apidoc you gave, there's also http://<yourtidalserver>:<port>/api/tes-6-dev/postscreen which is also a little helper they ship

Answer (score 0):

Just as a fair warning i know nothing about Cisco Tidal Scheduler.

However, i did do some digging around on their site anyway, it would appear that Tidal does have API's which appear to be compatible with C#. Hopefully this will help:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps11131/index.html

EDIT: Looks like this is likely what you're looking for as they explain:

This software works with Cisco Tidal Enterprise Scheduler to improve web services orchestration by:

Automating job scheduling